# Serilog SQL Server no entries when error is thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, serilog

I have Serilog setup with SQL Server, log entries were going when using a table I had initial added to Serilog's setup. However, I later tried to add column options (original table did not have that) and the new table was made with the columns, but I do not see any data being written to it.  If I change back to the old table name, entries are going in. Using new table name, if I remove the column options, still nothing is written when an error is thrown.

```
// Add Serilog
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) =>
        {
            configuration
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext() 
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Assembly", $"{name.Name}")    
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", $"{name.Version}")  
                .Enrich.With(services.GetService<UserIdEnricher>()!)
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDb"), 
                    sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                    {
                        TableName = "LogEventsNew",
                        AutoCreateSqlTable = true
                    }, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error, columnOptions: GetSqlColumnOptions());
        });

private static ColumnOptions GetSqlColumnOptions()
{
    var options = new ColumnOptions();

    options.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.MessageTemplate);
    options.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent);

    options.AdditionalColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn>
        {
            new SqlColumn
            {
                ColumnName = "UserId",
                AllowNull = true,
                DataType = SqlDbType.Int
            },
            new SqlColumn
            {
                ColumnName = "MachineName",
                AllowNull = false
            }
        };

    return options;
}
```

`TableName = LogEventsNew` is the new one that is not logging, that was made by Serilog on it's own when I started the application. The old table was called `LogEvents`, that has the default columns and is working when I point to that.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and connect to database.  In the explorer under Management are the log files which will give more info on the errors.

Comment: @jdweng tried that both showed a bulk insert happening. I ended up deleting the new table from the db and rebuilding the application and now its working.

Comment: You code must be using Migration to add table to the database.  The Migration would fail if the table already existed.  So you may need to check if table exists before adding.  You do not want to drop tables if there is data that you need.  Are you using a view for temp storage?  Always check if the view exists and remove before adding new one.

Comment: Did you try [enabling the self log](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics), as described in the documentation?

Comment: @jdweng I don't have migrations, not running those as we're using db first.  but i did have AutoCreateSqlTable = true setup in my MSSqlServerSinkOptions as table was being made automatically when i started the app. not sure why it didnt write at first, after deleting table and retrying it's writing now.

Comment: db First is no longer supported in Core.

Comment: @jdweng sorry i meant, we're using EF core power tools to bring in the entities we want, not making entities and pushing them using migrations, making tables first and then power tools to bring them in.